# Probability generating function for pascal distribution

Tags: probability-theory

The objective is to find the P.G.F of the Pascal($n,p$).

> $n = 1,2,3\ldots$
>
> $p$ $\in$ [0,1] and $q = 1-p$
>
> $p_x(k)=P(X=k)=\binom{k-1}{n-1}p^nq^{k-n}$
>
> $k = n,n+1,n+2,\ldots$.
>
> Show that the p.g.f of X is:
>
> $g_x(t)=(\frac{pt}{1-qt})^n$ for $|t |<q^{-1}$.

So my main goal is to put the expression such that I can make use of the binomial theorem and hopefully everything comes out nicely the thing is that I get stuck halfway..

$g_x(t)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{k-1}{n-1}p^nq^{k-n}t^k$

The first problem is to set n in the sum sign and not have k dictating it second would be to switch n and k such that one can use the binomial theorem. So I begin by checking how k and n relate.

from the sequence given I can deduce k to be:
$k = 2n-1$ one should be able to substitute in that instead for k.

thus:

$g_x(t)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{2n-2}{n-1}p^nq^{n-1}t^{2n-1}$

The problem here is that I don't really know where to go from here. another approach that I took was to rewrite the expression to:

$g_x(t)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{k}{n}p^nq^{k-n}t^k \frac{n}{k}$

Which I felt didn't really help me either...

Comment: Do you realise that $n$ is fixed once and for all?

Comment: Actually I haven't...that leaves me ever more confused actually..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a Pascal distribution, also kwown as negative binomial random variable, the p.g.f. is:

$$g(z)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}z^{k}\binom{k−1}{n−1}(1−p)^{k−n}p^n$$

Now, it's just a matter of massaging the summation in order to get a working formula. We start by effectively multiplying the summands by $1$, and thereby not changing the overall sum:

$$g(z)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}z^{k}\binom{k−1}{n−1}q^{k−n}p^n\cdot\frac{z^n}{z^n}$$

Now, since $p^n$ and $z^n$ do not depend on $k$, they can be pulled through the summation. We have:

$$\begin{align}
g(z)&=(pz)^n\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}z^{k}\binom{k−1}{n−1}q^{k−n}(z)^{-n}\\
&=(pz)^n\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\binom{k−1}{n−1}q^{k−n}(z)^{k-n}\\
&=(pz)^n\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\binom{k−1}{n−1}q^{k−n}(z)^{k-n}\\
&=(pz)^n\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\binom{k−1}{n−1}(qz)^{k−n}
\end{align}
$$
Now, let $i = k−n$, so that $k = i + n$. Changing the index on the summation, we get:
$$\begin{align}
\color{blue}{g(z)}&=(z)^n\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{i+n−1}{n−1}(qz)^{i}=(pz)^n[1-qz]^{-n}=\color{blue}{\left(\frac{pz}{1-qz}\right)^n}
\end{align}
$$
using the [sum of a negative binomial series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html)
$$
(1-x)^{-n}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty{-n \choose i}(-x)^i =\sum_{i=0}^\infty{i+n-1\choose n-1}x^i, \qquad\text{for every}\quad 0 ≤ x < 1
$$

Now, recall that the p.g.f. exists only if it is finite. $g(z)$ is finite when $qz < 1$, or equivalently when $\color{blue}{z < \frac{1}{(1 − p)}}$. And the proof is complete.

Comment: I assume that the mgf and the pgf are related which should imply that the solutions also are highly related...so i'll study it and try to solve it! thank you

Comment: @Drwk sorry, now edited

Comment: No problem! I can follow the solution as it is very clear but what bothers me is how one is supposed to realize to multiply with 1, that is $\frac{z^n}{z^n}$?

Comment: The trick is to use something related to a binomial sum, that is like $a^nb^{k-n}$; so we have, the term $z^k p^n q^{k-n}=p^n q^{-n} (qz)^k$ and we need $z^{n}$ for $p^n$ and $z^{-n}$ for $q^{-n}$ so we can multiply $p^n q^{-n} (qz)^k$ by $1=z^nz^{-n}$, and then we have $(pz)^n(qz)^{k-n}$.

Comment: Ok! I understand! Thank you!